# Foreach & Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm terribly confused on how I should be writing this function...it basically scores a test, and it WORKS for one user's values.

Let's say I want the values for the following user: `$id = 2`...this works!  If  `$id = array(2,3,4,5)` it doesn't work!

```
function get_score_a($id){
    // Case 4
    foreach($this->get_results_a($id,4)->row() as $key=>$a){
        if ($a >= 2 && $a <= 4) {
            $score_a += 2;
        } else if ($a > 4 && $a < 8) {
            $score_a += 3;
        } else if ($a > 8) {
            $score_a += floor($a - 8) * .5;
            $score_a += 3;
        }
    };

    return $score_a;
}


function get_results_a($id, $method) {
        $select_cols = array(
                            1 => array('a_1','a_2','a_4'),
                            2 => array('a_6','a_8','a_11','a_12','a_14'),
                            3 => array('a_3','a_10'),
                            4 => array('a_5','a_7','a_9','a_13')
                            );
        return $this->db->select($select_cols[$method])
                        ->where_in('id', $id)
                        ->get('be_survey');
    }
```

This returns a score...however, if I run multiple ids...it just adds up all the numbers, I think...

Instead I need this to output separate scores for individual users...

May it be noted that I'm a total noob!  So vivacious explanations are very much appreciated. :)

**Edit**
Please review my code...as I should have been more clear! Sorry!
I apologize!  *In summation,* this selects the correct values from the table, based on

And yes, my eyes hurt too!
**Edit**
I am too hasty!  This is a Codeigniter project!

Comment: "This returns a score." No it doesn't. It will return a parse error on the very first line.

Comment: are you using some PHP Framework, CodeIgniter? Why you are using `$this`?

Comment: hey, don't leave us hanging! "Based on" what?

Comment: Yes, JMC. I'm sorry, this is a CI project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, there is no `row()` for arrays.. just use `foreach ($array as $key=>$value)`
Secondly, inside the `foreach` loop $score_b is being incremented on each run with its previous value. So, your code is outputting the sum of all player scores.
use:

```
foreach(array(5,5,5,6,7,78,8,7,7,6,5) as $key=>$a){
         if ($a >= 0 && $a <= .5) {
             $score_b[$key] += 0;
         } else if ($a > .5 && $a < 2) {
             $score_b[$key] += 1;
         }
     else if ($a > 2 && $a < 4) {
             $score_b[$key] += 2;
         }
           else if ($a > 4) {
          $score_b[$key] += floor($a - 8) * .5;
             $score_b[$key] += 2;
         }
     };
```

$score_b will now be an array of scores.

**EDIT:**
Add the following in your code:

```
$id = array(2,3,4,5);
function get_score_array($ids) {
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $scores[$id] = get_score_a($id);
    }
    return $scores;
}
```

`$scores` will now be an array of `$id`=>`$score` pairs.
Also, adjust the above code, as per your framework (which I guess you are using)

Comment: Please see my edit! Sorry! :)  If this is still a solution, would you also include how to output/format this in html?  Again, I'm a total noob!

Comment: Haha. I will, I will. Would you be so kind as to explain your reasoning? (my solution was your edited part, not the first half).

Comment: I have three functions to do one task. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such method called `row()` on `array`. In fact, an `array` isn't strictly an *object*, so it doesn't have methods.

So, first of all, get rid of the `->row()` invocation.

Second, where are you pushing these scores onto an array? I don't see where that happens in your code. Initialize an empty array before the `foreach` loop, and push the `$score_b` variable onto the array at the end of the loop.

Comment: it wont work.. since he is incrementing the same `score_b` variable inside `foreach` loop and hence, outputting the sum of all player scores, rather than individual scores.

Answer (score 0):

Set a `$userID` variable outside the foreach loop like this:

```
$userScores = array(
    'bobby' = > array(5,5,5,6,7,78,8,7,7,6,5),
    'sue' = > array(5,5,5,6,7,78,8,7,7,6,5),
    'joe' = > array(5,5,5,6,7,78,8,7,7,6,5)
);

foreach($userScores as $name => $a){
    $score_b[$name] = 0; //initialize
    if ($a >= 0 && $a <= .5) {
         $score_b[$name] += 0;
    } else if ($a > .5 && $a < 2) {
    $score_b[$name] += 1;
     }
 else if ($a > 2 && $a < 4) {
         $score_b[$name] += 2;
     }
       else if ($a > 4) {
      $score_b[$name] += floor($a - 8) * .5;
         $score_b[$name] += 2;
     }
 };
```

your end result should be something like (I didn't do any actual math)

```
$score_b['bobby'][100]
$score_b['sue'][75]
$score_b['joe'[90]
```

Comment: I'm liking the looks of this, JMC...I'll give this a try!

Comment: Do you need to initialize the `$score_b[$name]` variable before using the `+=` operator anyone? If that's the problem, try adding `score_b[$name] = 0;` just after the `foreach`